# Fast way to extract hashtags, user mentions and urls from tweet text?

Tags: java, regex, twitter

I'm trying to find a fast way to get an array of Strings made for each: 1- hashtags, 2- user mentions 3- urls in a tweet text. I have the tweets text in csv file.

My way to solve the problem takes too long processing time and I wonder if I can optimize my code a bit. I will show my regex rules for each matching type but just not to post a long code I will show only how I'm matching the hashtags. The same technique is for urls and user mentions.

Here it is:

```
public static String hashtagRegex = "^#\\w+|\\s#\\w+";
public static Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile(hashtagRegex);

public static String urlRegex = "http+://[\\S]+|https+://[\\S]+";
public static Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex);

public static String mentionRegex = "^@\\w+|\\s@\\w+";
public static Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile(mentionRegex);

public static String[] getHashtag(String text) {
   String hashtags[];
   matcher = hashtagPattern.matcher(tweet.getText());

    if ( matcher.find() ) {
        hashtags = new String[matcher.groupCount()];
        for ( int i = 0; matcher.find(); i++ ) {
                    //Also i'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            hashtags[i] = matcher.group().replace(" ", "").replace("#", "");
        }
    }

   return hashtags;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Matcher#groupCount` gives you the number of capturing groups, *not* the number of matches. That's why you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (in your case, the array is initialized with a size of zero). Instead of an array, you might want to use a `List` for collecting your matches, which dynamically grows.

One (potential) approach for speeding up might be to tokenize the text on whitespaces, and then just check the tokens' beginnings for fragments such as `http`, `@` or `#`. This way, you can avoid the regular expressions completely. (haven't profiled, so I cannot tell about the performance impact).

Comment: The code to tokenize on whitespaces is way simpler than using a regex, and for that a definite upvote!